# Mutual information of two image patches with different size

Tags: image

I need to compute mutual information of two image patches. I know how to compute it if the two patches are the same size. But if the size is different, how can I compute the mutual information(or joint histogram between the two patches)?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question about algorithms, more than programming.

The answer depends on the definition of *mutual information*. If it's a histogram representing the occurrance of (some property) per pixel, then it makes sense to normalize your features. In particular, *scale your features*.

For example, if you have two inputs *X1* (image 100x100px) and *X2* (image 200x200px) and you want to look at the number of red pixels in them (red: R component > G+B components together). Then your feature (# red pixels) scales linearly with the number of pixels in the image. In this example, I would recommend rewriting the number of red pixels to the fraction of red pixels. For X1 that means dividing by 10000, for X2 it's a dividion by 40000. After that scaling, both features _red_X1_ and _red_X2_ are in the 0 ... 1 range and can be compared.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry that I didn't describe my problem clearly. The two image patch maybe not a rectangle area, for example plate-like or snake-like area. Do you have some good ideas?

Comment: Biggest question: what is the feature you want to compare / merge between the images?